# How to erase the same elements in struct using a vector

Tags: c++, vector, struct

```
#include <iostream>
#include<algorithm>
#include<string>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;

struct Student {
    string name;
    string number;
    double score;
};

bool compare(const Student& a, const Student& b) {
    return a.score > b.score;
}

int main()
{
    vector<Student> v;
    Student student;

    int x = 500;
    Student stu[x];
    int i = 0;


    do {
        cout<<"Please enter the name of the student.: ";
        getline(cin, stu[i].name,'\n');
        // is the name properly typed in?"
        while(stu[i].name == "") {
            cout<<"Please enter a proper name.: ";
            getline(cin, stu[i].name,'\n');
        }
        if(stu[i].name == "QUIT") {
            break;
        }

        cout<<"Please enter the student number.: ";
        cin>>stu[i].number;

        cout<<"Please enter the score.: ";
        cin>>stu[i].score;
        // is the score in the range?
        while(stu[i].score <= 0 || stu[i].score >=100) {
            cout<<"The score must be in the range of 0~100. \n"
                <<"Please enter a proper score.: ";
            cin>>stu[i].score;
        }
        i++;
        cin.ignore();
        v.push_back(student);


    } while (stu[i-1].name != "0" && stu[i-1].number != "0" && stu[i-1].score != 0);

    sort(stu, stu+i, compare);
    v.erase(unique(v.begin(), v.end()), v.end());
}
```

I want first want to sort the elements, and if there are same elements typed in, erase them. 
I tried to use " v.erase(unique(v.begin(), v.end()), v.end()) ", but it doesn't work. I can't find out what is the problem. Is there something I missed out?

Comment: `Student stu[x];` -- You're using `vector`, so why are you using this non-standard C++ syntax?  That should simply be `std::vector<Student> stu(x);`.  Arrays in C++ must have their sizes denoted by a constant expression, not a runtime value.

Comment: `Student` doesn't have `operator<` needed to `std::sort`, or you need to pass your comparer to `std::sort` too.

Comment: In the same way, `std::unique`  requires `operator ==` or a BinaryPredicate.

Comment: `sort(stu, stu+i, compare);` -- Also, I vaguely recall that using those non-standard variable-length arrays within STL algorithm functions was broken for some versions of g++.  Thus either use *real* arrays, not VLA's, or use actual containers such as `std::array` or `std::vector`.